# gem not working in Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, ruby, gem

On a freshly installed Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit I installed Cygwin (64) and some of its packages, including Ruby. I have also installed Ruby using the Ruby installer, because I'll likely need it for both the default Windows shells and Cygwin.

Now when I try to execute a `gem` command like `gem list` or `gem install foo`, I get a weird error I failed to solve within the last few hours of searching the internet.

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-cygwin]

$ gem -v
2.4.8

$ gem list
ERROR:  Loading command: list (Fiddle::DLError)
        can't load kernel32
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

$ gem install sass
ERROR:  Loading command: install (Fiddle::DLError)
        can't load kernel32
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

However, with the native Windows version, from the Windows CMD, it works without any problems. I cannot however use native Windows Ruby stuff from Cygwin, because that gives me errors, but that's not the question here anyway.

With Process Monitor I figured out that Ruby tries to open `C:\cygwin64\bin\kernel32.dll` and fails, because that file is not there. I tried copying the `kernel32.dll` from `C:\Windows\System32` and the one from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` into that Cygwin `bin` folder and still got the same error (apart from that it then said *can't load kernel32.dll*), although the Process Monitor didn't show a `NAME NOT FOUND` error anymore.

What magic is happening here? I'd really like to understand what's wrong here. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a unexpected result of cygwin 2.5.2 release

https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-06/msg00378.html

As workaround, downgrade cygwin package to 2.5.1

Comment: Problem solved https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-06/msg00054.html

Comment: "Problem solved" That only fixes the problem when you install Ruby through the Cygwin installer, right? I'm getting this error while trying to install via RVM, so I guess my only option is to downgrade Cygwin.

Comment: If ruby is not installed with "Cygwin installer" than is not a a cygwin programs and I do not see why it should care about cygwin dll loader.

Comment: RVM works by downloading and compiling Ruby from source. So if you're running it in a Cygwin environment, then the resulting binaries will be a "Cygwin program". Anyway, downgrading Cygwin to 2.5.1 did resolve my problem.

Comment: @Ajedi32, in case this is still a problem for you, I posted an answer for RVM installed rubies below. I didn't really want to downgrade my Cygwin version!

Answer (score 6):

A way to fix this without changing the rvm build process is:

`ln -s /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll /usr/lib/kernel32`

This happens because ruby is looking for a shared library named simply `kernel32`. Cygwin 2.5.1 and earlier automatically added the ".dll" extension to shared library loads. But cygwin 2.5.2 introduced a patch requiring full shared library filenames. Adding a symbolic link within the library search path (`/usr/lib`) allows the library to be found even when loaded with the old-style name.

Comment: +1 IMHO this solution is the neatest as there is no need to edit the `resolv.rb`. Worked with Cygwin 2.6.0 and rbenv

Answer (score 5):

I installed ruby using rvm so the updated Cygwin ruby binaries weren't much help and I didn't really want to downgrade my Cygwin installation - how would I know when it was safe to upgrade again?

Following the information in Michael D's answer, the problem appears to be in the `resolv.rb` file located in `~\.rvm\rubies\ruby-<version>\lib\ruby\<version>\win32` (in my case `~\.rvm\rubies\ruby-2.1.7\lib\ruby\2.1.0\win32`).

Somewhere near the top of this file, there is the code

```
module Kernel32
  extend Importer
  dlload "kernel32"
end
```

Simply changing the `dlload "kernel32"` line to `dlload "kernel32.dll"` seemed to fix it for me. Alternatively using the full path

```
dlload "c:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll"
```

also worked, but it seems to be the extension that is the crucial bit (the full path without the extension also doesn't work).

This may have been fixed in a more recent version of rvm, but I didn't want to go through the hassle of updating and reinstalling, so this works for me. Or course this would likely need to be changed for all installed rubies.

Comment: [The problem is solved since 28 June](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-06/msg00054.html).

I don't recommend using an rvm installation from Cygwin. I only had problems with that, at the latest when gems need to be compiled. And I don't see any problems with the Cygwin version (apart from this one, which has been fixed and could be workarounded easily).

Comment: @Neon, well I prefer to use rvm so that I can easily test different ruby versions and use gemsets so for me the problem was not solved, but each to their own.

Comment: Also, cygwin doesn't provide the latest ruby versions. For example 2.3.1 is not available in the repos. Also, there are projects that *use* rvm specifically, to properly manage the ruby version which is used.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby package has problem loading native libraries (at least kernel32.dll). The problem comes from a call to `dns.getresource("_rubygems._tcp.#{host}", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::SRV)` which probably make a native call to `kernel32.dll` hence loading the `kernel32.dll` library.

If you specify the full path to the library, it will work correctly.

```
kernel = Fiddle::Handle.new("c:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll")
```

To solve the issue, try the following:

1. Require `devkit` when running `extconf.rb` as follows: `ruby -rdevkit extconf.rb` , or just adding `require "devkit"` to `extconf.rb` then running the script normally.
2. Run the `devkitvars.bat` script from the devkit to configure the `PATH` with the toolchain before compiling.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want me to do. I'm just using `gem`, no scripts from my side. So I'm not able to specify a full path and I don't know what's the `extconf.rb` is nor how or when to use it. I'm also not compiling anything.

Please give some further instructions so I can test what you advised.

Comment: To know more about `extconf.rb` please refer [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Extending_Ruby_Creating_a_Makefile_with_extconf.rb.html). To check the loading of `kernel32.dll` try to use [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Extending_Ruby_Creating_a_Makefile_with_extconf.rb.html) script.

Comment: I am sorry, I seem to have attached the same link twice, [here's](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/10/attachment/unable_to_load_kernel32_testcase.rb) the script I spoke about in the previous comment.